# Point in polygon analysis in excel

Tags: geospatial, geocoding, excel

In excel, I have one table where each row corresponds to a geospatial point, with exact x and y coordinates. Total number of rows is over 200,000, for example:

[image]

In a separate table, I have a list of grids created in QGIS and exported as a csv file. These grids outline left, right and bottom, top coordinates. Total number of rows is just over 8000, for example:

[image]

so essentially, person 1 should be assigned to grid a, person 2 to grid b, and so on. The ultimate goal is to get, for each grid, a total count of IDs within each grid.

I've tried all sorts of options with vlookup, lookup and conditional statements and so on, but at a dead end. Any help would be appreciated!!

Just for context, I can only use excel for this issue, rather than other GIS tools.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to check if ID1 x_coordinate is greater than grid_a left and is less than grid_a right. And if ID1 y_coordinate is less than Grid_a top and greater than Grid_a bottom. If all those conditions are met, then ID1 belong to grid_a. So, in excel terms, a combination of IF and AND will be the solution.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Grzegorz :)